# Multiple values in WHERE based on condition

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a input parameter, based on it I have to also include NULL and EMPTY VALUES.

```
If(TYPE=='HIGH') THEN TYPE='HIGH' OR TYPE ='' OR TYPE IS NULL
IF(TYPE=='LOW') THEN TYPE='LOW'
```

Query I tried but its not working.

```
SELECT * FROM PAYRECORDS
WHERE (TYPE =(CASE WHEN TYPE=:IP_TYPE THEN TYPE END) 
OR TYPE IS NULL OR TYPE='')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use boolean logic:

```
WHERE (:IP_TYPE = 'HIGH' AND (TYPE = 'HIGH' OR TYPE = '' OR TYPE IS NULL)
      ) OR
      (:IP_TYPE = 'LOW' AND TYPE = 'LOW')
```

Or more succinctly:

```
WHERE :IP_TYPE = TYPE OR
      (:IP_TYPE = 'HIGH' AND (TYPE = '' OR TYPE IS NULL))
```

Answer (score 3):

In Oracle, an empty string `''` is the same as `NULL`; so your filter can simply be:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   PAYRECORDS
WHERE  :ip_type = type
OR     (:ip_type = 'HIGH' AND type IS NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `NVL()` to consider that when column `type` isn't populated then it should be considered as `HIGH`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   PAYRECORDS
WHERE  NVL(type, 'HIGH') = :ip_type;
```